# Where do I create my layout in the Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, layout, master-pages

In ASP.Net you'd create a MasterPage and have whatever pages use that.

I need my pages to use the same basic layout. Where do I create it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [Zend Framework Quickstart section on layouts](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-layout.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you read some tutorial about Zend Framework ; for instance, you might want to go through the 10 existing chapters of the ebook [Zend Framework: Surviving The Deep End](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0).

About your specific question, you'll especially be interested by [Chapter 10. Setting The Design With Zend_View, Zend_Layout, HTML 5 and Yahoo! User Interface Library](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/setting.the.design.with.zend.view.zend.layout.html.5.and.yahoo.user.interface.library), and, more specifically, the [10.2.1. Layouts](http://survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/setting.the.design.with.zend.view.zend.layout.html.5.and.yahoo.user.interface.library#zfbook.setting.the.design.with.zend.view.zend.layout.html.5.and.yahoo.user.interface.library.zend.view.object.oriented.templating.layouts) section.